# Make a class hierarchy data classes using a meta class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am redesigning a library, which at the moment uses a lot of boilerplate code in a double hierarchy of classes / metaclasses, to attempt to make it much cleaner and reuse as much as possible what dataclasses already provides.

For the library itself it is not an issue to add the `@dataclass` decorator when defining each and every subclasses.

However, and this is my first question: shouldn't it be the default behavior, that if a class inherits from a `dataclass` then it itself becomes a `dataclass`?

But the issue is that users of the library should be able to create subclasses without knowing about all the internal details (so they should not be asked to decorate the subclasses they define).

My solution uses a meta class to force the decorator when creating the class:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Any, Tuple, Dict
from abc import ABC, ABCMeta
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

class CommandType(ABCMeta):
    def __new__(mcs, name: str, bases: Tuple[CommandType, type, ...], dct: Dict[str, Any]):
        return dataclass(super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, dct))

    def __getattribute__(cls, item):
        try:
            return super().__getattribute__('__dataclass_fields__')[item]
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):
            pass
        return ABCMeta.__getattribute__(cls, item)

    def __contains__(cls, item) -> bool:
        return item in cls.__dataclass_fields__

class Command(ABC, metaclass=CommandType):
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        ...  # This will dynamically add fields based on configuration files

class SubCommandA(Command):
    A: float = field(metadata={'comment': 'This is parameter A'})

class SubCommandB(Command):
    B: float = field(metadata={'comment': 'This is parameter B'})
```

This seems to be working nicely for what I want:

```
SubCommandA(A=1).A  # 1
SubCommandB.B # Field(...)
```

Does that make sense? Is there any obvious issue with the implementation?

More as a thought than as a question my custom implementation of `__getattr__` in the meta class seems quite useful. Am I missing something? Why doesn't `dataclass` provides that mechanism as well?

I also initially tried to put all that in `__init_subclass__` instead of a dedicated meta class, as this was mostly the point of my refactoring, but it doesn't seem feasible.